# Sort data in MySql Data Base

Tags: mysql, date, bigdata

I make several measurement tests. I would like to save 3000 channels at 1 point by minute during one month (for one test) in a MySQL database. 
I would like to know how can I struct my tables to improve research by channels between two date.

Should I create a table by test or a table by channel or both solution?

I also know there are different kinds of date in MySql. Which one is the best one for my application?

We tried 2 solutions but once there are lot of data, all request begin to be very very slow :

- One table by channels with 3 columns (Test_number, Date, Data )
- One big table with 4 columns (Channel,Test_number, Date , Data) with an index on (Channel, test number)

I use Labview with MSQL Connector 5.3 And MySql WorkBench for testing my request.

```
CREATE TABLE `mesure_ana_in` (
  `mesure_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `test_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mesure_id`),
  KEY `mai_date_idx` (`test_number`,`channel`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61552218 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;
```

(this table (mesure_ana_in) has two "test_number" :

- 11: is filled at 1Hz by 1010 channels during 15hours
- 12: is filled at 0.2Hz by 1010 channels during 4 days

My Data table has 57093592 rows. And this request return 53282 rows in 1 minute.)

```
SELECT
  `Data`,
  `Date`,
  `Test_number`
FROM `mesure_ana_in`
WHERE `Date` >= '20160912104313'
      AND `Date` <= '20160912154313'
      AND `Channel` = 3082
      AND `Test_number` = 11
ORDER BY `Date` ASC;
```

It has One index

```
ADD INDEX `idx` (`Test_number` ASC, `channel` ASC, `date` ASC);
```

And  when I want to export all data of a test , I proceed by time chunk (4 hours) of channel and it could take Several hours

Thanks;)

Marc

Comment: Did you create and index for `DATE` or for any other field on the `WHERE`?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

U

Answer (score 0):

After reading a litle more you should go with second option the big table. The problem is you didnt include `DATE` as part of your index.

Also dont store time as string use the proper **[DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)** type

Comment: I add lots of information like create statement and index of table. I don't know if I can reduce the request time. I think (hope) it is possible. I don't want one answer but some tips to improve my request or my database strucure.

Comment: I told you, your question isnt complete, you need include the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues...

- Shrinking the data will speed up queries; some of the items below address that.
- You probably have a 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`; if so, get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  (8 bytes/row saved)
- If you can replace the PK, then the order of the columns in the new PK will be important.  For the one query you mentioned, having `test_number` or `channel` first is important; `date` should be last.  (This avoids the overhead of a secondary index and, more importantly, avoids jumping between the secondary key and the PK.)
- What version are you using?  Newer version take 5 bytes for `DATETIME` and for `TIMESTAMP`, so it does not matter which you use.
- `data` is `NULLable`; did you really want that?
- Can you `INSERT` multiple rows at the same time?  This will help a lot in ingestion speed.
- `FLOAT` gives you about 7 significant digits; this is plenty good for *most* scientific measurements.  (Saves 4 bytes over `DOUBLE`.)
- `test_num` and `channel` are 4-byte signed integers.  Won't a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (range 0..65K) suffice?  See also `MEDIUMINT` and `TINYINT`.
- If you plan to have other `SELECTs`, please show them, too.  A good set of indexes requires looking at all `SELECTs` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will soon answer. We are asking a spécialist for improving my sql server configuration and making better request and database structure. after that I will send more information. :)

Comment: Configuration changes, with few exceptions, will not give you much performance improvement.  The main setting to check is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of _available_ RAM.

Comment: If you would like more configuration critique, provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`, plus how much RAM you have.